# Is there a taste or texture difference between gravity breweries and those that use pumps?

Tags: breweries

I visited the UK's oldest licensed brewery, [the Three Tuns](http://www.threetunsbrewery.co.uk/history), in Shropshire, which has been licenced since 1642. One of its key features is that all transfers can be carried out using gravity:

- all raw materials are brought to the top of the tower, and then each movement of materials or fluids is carried out using gravity - not pumps

My question is: does this provide a difference in flavour, texture or other qualities to beers from those breweries that use pumps? I can imagine it might, as pumps cause agitation that won't exist in a simple pipe letting liquid flow downhill.

(additional information: the Three Tuns is well worth a visit - all the beers on show that day were delicious)

Comment: As you say - pumps cause agitation that gravity fed kits wont. Is that going be enough to taste? I don't think so...

Comment: less tubing etc to have to worry about cleaning as well I'd imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly not. Agitation won't change the properties of the beer enough as such. BUT... when pumping, it is harder to avoid oxygen/air being mixed into the wort/beer. Oxygen is very bad for the beer in most stages of the brewing process. So if you have a pumping system, it needs to be a good one that doesn't wirl air into the wort/beer.

The only stage in the brewing process where you actually want as much oxygen/air as possible is when pitching the yeast. At every other stage you will get oxidation which is one of the top reasons for off flavours, stuck fermentations, etc.